# After migrating to VITE Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Role')

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, vite

`KVSWebRTC is undefined` after I migrated my project from VUE CLI to VITE.

I adjusted all the imports and environment variables to VITE.

Before migration

`const KVSWebRTC = require('amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc');`

after migration

`import KVSWebRTC from 'amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc';`

Accessing environment variables was before

`const accessKeyId = process.env.VUE_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;`

and now

`const accessKeyId = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;`

The app does run and everything works, it is just this error that `KVSWebRTC` is undefined.

I am not sure if there is another configuration I have to take.

My I also added

```
optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc']
  },
```

to the `vite.config.js`.

Still have this problem.

Comment: There's no Role in the code you posted. Please, post the whole error instead of putting it to the title. If Role is in your own code then add code as well